# Function from pandas_datareader doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I have installed pandas-datareader using pip. I can import the module, but why I can't get working this command `from pandas_datareader import data as wb` ? I'm using a virtual environment in VSC and I have the latest version of pip.

[image]

Comment: Try `import pandas_datareader.data as web` and make sure that you installed data reader in the environment that you are running your code.

Comment: Yes it is installed in the environment, and ```web``` didn't make a difference

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: @Gato changing the alias does not matter. The change is not using from: `import pandas_datareader.data as web`

Comment: @emmacb I don't get any error message. VSC just doesn't recognise ```import pandas_datareader``` or ```from pandas_datareader```. I'm trying to follow this example where it apparently works 
https://amangupta16.medium.com/portfolio-optimization-using-python-part-1-2-9fd80097a606

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `from` and use:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd

df = web.DataReader('BTC-USD', 'yahoo', start='2022-01-01', end='2022-06-14')
df.tail(10)
```

[image]